# Looking for Multi-Platform Memory Leak detection programs

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, multiplatform, memory-profiling

Ok I have a school assignment to basically pick 3 memory leak detecting programs and run them on a bunch of c++ programs that the teacher supplies us and see how they compare to each other. These 3 programs have to be multi-platform and this is where I'm stuck. I have only been able to find one called valgrind which works on both MAC OSX and Linux. Does anybody know of a few others? Almost everything I find seems to be for only one OS or I have to pay for it. I don't have to actually run them on each OS they just have to have a version that will run on another OS. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Turns out I completely misunderstood my assignment and that I just have to have like say 1 for linux and 2 for windows. Basically I can't have all 3 for one OS. This makes things a heck of a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since leak detection programs uses OS specific instrumentation code which injected to your code, there aren't many multi platform solutions, as each OS has it's own memory management features.

I used to work with bounds-checker, AQTime (more modern) but they both run on windows based software.
if your code is pure C++ than you can just port it to MS environment - and check it there.

Comment: you can use a trial version for homework... they won't be angry with you :-)

Answer (score 0):

IBM's [purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) has Linux, Windows and various Unix versions (not sure about OSX). It is paid software, but you may be able to get away with using the trial version.

Answer (score 0):

You might try Electric Fence ([efence](http://freshmeat.net/projects/efence/))